# Javax JSON Response only works with ".toString"

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following problem. If I return the Statement like that it works:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Path("foo")
  public Response foo(Model bar) throws CustomException {
    // do parsing and return response
    JSONObject response = fooBar.handleRequest(bar);
    return Response.status(HTTP_STATUS).entity(response.toString()).build();
  }
```

If I try it without ".toString()" i get an empty json object.
Couldn't find any answer until now...

Does someone know why?

Comment: Depending on the Jackson configuration, the serializer uses fields and/or getters to work. By default, it uses public getters, and if JSONObject has none (which is the case if you use org.json.JSONObject), no serialization occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the return type to object and just return the `JSONObject` without converting it to `String`. Jackson will take care of the conversion.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Path("foo")
  public Object foo(Model bar) throws CustomException {
    // do parsing and return response
    JSONObject response = fooBar.handleRequest(bar);
    return response;
  }
```

Comment: With this solution I get an Http Error 500. It returns the response but then it fails somewhere.

Comment: 500 means Internal server error. You need to trace the error by looking into the server logs